# How many characters can NSString have

Tags: javascript, iphone, nsstring, webview

I am trying to return a string from Javascript:

```
   [myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"myJavaScriptFunction()"];
```

for short strings, the return is OK.
However, when I return a very long string(say 5000 characters in the string), I couldn't get anything.

So I am guessing it might due to the NSString Size limitation OR my "var jvString" size limitation.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: You can find more information on the maximum size of a NSString object here, if that helps:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482641/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-an-nsstring-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the method `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` returns `nil`, it means something has gone wrong. This is most likely **not** because of `NSString` size limitations, but for one of the following reasons:

- the javascript execution took longer than 10 seconds
- the script allocated more than 10 MB

From the documentation:

> JavaScript execution time is limited to 10 seconds for each top-level
>   entry point. If your script executes for more than 10 seconds, the web
>   view stops executing the script. This is likely to occur at a random
>   place in your code, so unintended consequences may result. This limit
>   is imposed because JavaScript execution may cause the main thread to
>   block, so when scripts are running, the user is not able to interact
>   with the webpage.
>
> JavaScript allocations are also limited to 10 MB. The web view raises
>   an exception if you exceed this limit on the total memory allocation
>   for JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the 32 bit structure it should have a max length of 2^31-1 characters which should be enough ;)

Comment: Thanks for your response. However,it seems that I can only accept one answer. Thanks.