# How long can a string be in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the maximum length of an NSString object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482641/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-an-nsstring-object)

I'm trying to decide on a good way to store my tile data on the parse database. What I need is to store 24x24 values, not sure how long those values will be, but let's say I need to store 24x24 bytes (giving me 256 possibilities for each tile). I was thinking of storing them in a big string, is that possible? is there a limit on how big a string should be? or is there a better way to do this in objective c?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Please, *don't de-normalize a database unless fully scrutinized*. Also, "256" is a very small number these days; consider all the programs that would break if strings could not be "significantly larger".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re: string length, I don't think there's a hard limit on the length of a string.  But in terms of storing this type of data, how about a multi-dimensional array?  Here's a discussion on the topic.

[How to declare a two dimensional array of string type in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638129/how-to-declare-a-two-dimensional-array-of-string-type-in-objective-c)

Comment: There must be a hard limit. `-[NSString length]` returns an `NSUInteger`, and `characterAtIndex:` takes one.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum length is determined by the size of NSUInteger (so, billions).

This question has already been asked and answered on stackoverflow here 
[What is the maximum length of an NSString object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482641/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-an-nsstring-object)